# My IFRAME facebook app doesn't work in Opera and IE

Tags: facebook, opera, fbml

It works nicely in FF and Chrome, but in Opera I get timeout error. The loading animation is going and going on but nothing appears. Could you please help me? My deadline comes tommorow :-(

Pastebin entire source code: http://pastebin.com/yjFWwqPv

Answer (score 0):

Facebook connect is broken in Opera due to the problem I explained here:

http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2010/07/20/postmessage-s-targetorigin-and-security

I don't think there is anything you can do about it except waiting for either Opera or Facebook to fix it. Due to the nature of the problem is pretty hard to work around - unless, I guess, you make a local copy of http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js with a bugfix in it. That fix should be as simple as finding this code:

```
FB.XD._origin=(window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/'+FB.guid())
```

and remove the '+FB.guid()' part. While I know that this will avoid the Opera security policy violation, I'm not sure if this workaround will cause the script to fail in other ways - untested.